# change checkbox background image when it disabled

Tags: android

I want to change my checkbox image when it is disabled.
I used this code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_v" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_v" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox"/>

</selector>
```

but here I can not find the way how to set item on disabled state.
So how to find disable state using xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item is disabled when `state_enabled` is set to `false`. So you would do something like this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_v" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_v" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    ...
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    ...
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox"/>

</selector>
```